# Utilizing data from input file (string and int) and utilizing in loop

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, input, int

I must create a program that gets data from an input file and from that returns an average and maximum (both boiling point and associated string 'substance').  Data from the given input file follows:

```
Acetaldehyde    20.8
Acetone     50.5
Acetylene   -84
Ammonia     -35.5
Aniline     184.4
Benzene     80.4
Chloroform  62.2
Ethane      -88
Ether       35
Furfurol    161.7
Glycerin    290
Glycerine   290
Naphthalene 218
Nitrobenzene    210.9
Petrol      95
Petroleum   210
Phenol      182
Propane     -43
Propylene   -47.7
Tar     300
Toluene     110.6
Turpentine  160
Water       100
Xylene      142.7
```

I know the code to load the input data.  However, I am not sure what data to pull from it. This is what I have until this point:

```
int boiling, maximum=0,sum=0;
string substance;

///declare input stream variable
ifstream inData;

///open input file
inData.open("input.txt");

///Read the boiling temps
inData>>substance,boiling;
```

The second part of the question would be utilizing the 'string' variable from the input file in a 'for' loop, since I'm not sure what else would be used as parameters for the loop. I have no idea how to go about doing this and any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

I'm certain I have a case of tunnel vision and a huge problem with my syntax and am doing something completely and obviously wrong but I am not able to wrap my head around the problem, thus far. If it helps, we are at the point of discussing 'for' loops, in class.

****EDIT****

Thus Far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
///declare variables
double boiling, maximum=0,sum=0;
string substance, substancemax;

///declare input stream variable
ifstream inData;

///open input file
inData.open("input.txt");

///Read the boiling temps
inData>>substance>>boiling;

cout<<"Common Chemicals & Substances:"<<endl;
cout<<left<<setw(10)<<"Substance"
    <<right<<setw(13)<<"Boiling Point"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<left<<setw(10)<<substance
    <<right<<setw(13)<<boiling<<endl;
    ///run a loop w/ 'if' to read the data and calculate the minimum
while(inData)
{
    ///read temperature
    inData>>boiling;
    sum=sum+boiling;

        ///compare boiling with current maximum w/ 'if'
    if (boiling>maximum)
    {
        substancemax=substance;   ///update max substance
    }
}
///Display the data to the screen
cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
cout<<"\nThe average boiling point is "<<sum/24.0<<endl;
cout<<"\nThe substance with the highest BP is "<<substancemax<<endl;
cout<<"\nThe highest boiling point is "<<maximum<<endl;

///close the input file
inData.close();


    return 0;
    }
```

The parameters of the 'while' statement still eludes me, likely in addition to other issues.

********FINAL EDIT************

I have the program working with the 'for' loop (which I assume is required since that is the chapter we are on) minus the fact that it outputs a number in the boiling point row.  I am not sure where this number comes from

Common Chemicals & Substances:

### Substance           Boiling Point

```
                1.48738e+103
```

Acetaldehyde        20.8
Acetone             50.5
Acetylene           -84
Ammonia             -35.5
Aniline             184.4
Benzene             80.4
Chloroform          62.2
Ethane              -88
Ether               35
Furfurol            161.7
Glycerin            290
Glycerine           290
Naphthalene         218
Nitrobenzene        210.9
Petrol              95
Petroleum           210
Phenol              182
Propane             -43
Propylene           -47.7
Tar                 300
Toluene             110.6
Turpentine          160
Water               100
Xylene              142.7

The average boiling point is 109.95

The substance with the highest BP is Tar

The highest boiling point is 300.00

my coding is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
///declare variables
double boiling, maximum=0,sum=0,counter=0;
string substance, substancemax;

///declare input stream variable
ifstream inData;

///open input file
inData.open("input.txt");

///Label for file
cout<<"Common Chemicals & Substances:"<<endl;
cout<<left<<setw(20)<<"Substance"
<<"Boiling Point"<<endl;
cout<<"--------------------------------------"<<endl;

    ///run a loop w/ 'if' to read the data and calculate the minimum
for(counter=0;counter<=24;counter++)
{
cout<<left<<setw(20)<<substance
    <<left<<boiling<<endl;

    ///read temperature
    inData>>substance>>boiling;
    sum=sum+boiling;

        ///compare boiling with current maximum w/ 'if'
    if (boiling>maximum)
    {
        maximum = boiling;          ///update max boiling temp
        substancemax=substance;   ///update max substance
    }
}
///Display the data to the screen
cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);
cout<<"\nThe average boiling point is "<<sum/counter<<endl;
cout<<"\nThe substance with the highest BP is "<<substancemax<<endl;
cout<<"\nThe highest boiling point is "<<maximum<<endl;

///close the input file
inData.close();

    return 0;
    }
```

I am not sure where this output "1.48738e+103" comes from or how to eliminate it!

Comment: I think you need to go back to your class-notes or your text-book and study the stream input operator `>>` some more, and how to use it to read multiple values.

Comment: I also recommend you study what the `>>` operator function returns, and how a stream object could be used to check its status.

Comment: `110.6` does not look like an `int`. It looks more like a `float` or `double`. What if you had two strings, one for reading the name from the file, and one to hold the name of the current `namemax` to go along with your `max`? (you update both when `boiling > max`) Then at then end you would have both the name and boiling point for the substance with the max boiling point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if we can't un-tunnel the tunnel vision. You want to find the substance with the max boiling point (both the name and temperature), and then you want to find the average boiling point of all substances. In order to save the name of the substance with the max boiling point, and the boiling point itself will take two variables, as `std::string` and a `double`, say `namemax` and `max`.

You also need to compute the average boiling point. To compute an average you will need a `double` to hold the `sum` and then an integer value to hold the number of boiling points read. (say `size_t cnt = 0;`)

It is then a matter of reading each `name` and `boiling` point (which should be `std::string` and `double`, respectively) As you loop reading the `name` and `boiling`, within your loop you want to compare if `boiling > max` and if so, update `max = boiling;` and `namemax = name;` to capture the substance and boiling point as the new max. You update the counter `cnt` on each pair of `name` and `boiling` read.

When your loop exits, you have `namemax` and `max` containing the substance with the highest boiling point, so all that remains is computing the average boiling point as `sum / cnt`.

To put that together start with declaring your variables and opening your file, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient arguments\n"
                << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    double boiling, sum = 0, max = 0;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    std::string name, namemax;
    std::ifstream f(argv[1]);
```

Now loop reading the `name` and `boiling` from each line. **Note:** how you control the read loop based on the successful read of **both** `name` and `boiling`, e.g.

```
    while (f >> name && f >> boiling) {
        sum += boiling;                   /* update sum with boiling */
        if (boiling > max) {              /* is boiling > max?, if so */
            max = boiling;                /* update max */
            namemax = name;               /* update namenax */
        }
        cnt++;                            /* increment counter */
    }
```

Now all that remains is computing the average and outputting the results (which you can do all at once):

```
    std::cout << "average boiling pt. of " << cnt << " substances\n  "
            << sum / cnt
            << "\n\nsubstance with max boiling point\n  " << namemax
            << "  (" << max << ")\n";
}
```

Done! Putting it altogether you can do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient arguments\n"
                << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    double boiling, sum = 0, max = 0;
    size_t cnt = 0;
    std::string name, namemax;
    std::ifstream f(argv[1]);

    while (f >> name && f >> boiling) {
        sum += boiling;
        if (boiling > max) {
            max = boiling;
            namemax = name;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    std::cout << "average boiling pt. of " << cnt << " substances\n  "
            << sum / cnt
            << "\n\nsubstance with max boiling point\n  " << namemax
            << "  (" << max << ")\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/boilingpt dat/boiling.txt
average boiling pt. of 24 substances
  108.583

substance with max boiling point
  Tar  (300)
```

**Adding Output Of Each Line**

Per-your comment, you also need to output each of the values read from the file. You can do that at the beginning of your loop and simply output the values. But, let's introduce you to `std::setw()` which allows you to set the width of the next output (the `name`) so that when you output `boiling` they will be in a nice column and not staggered back and forth. To use `std::setw()`, you just provide the width, e.g. `std::setw(12)` will work in your case. The `std::setw()` function is in the `<iomanip>` header, so add `#include <iomanip>` up top.

When you use `std::setw()` you also want to make sure the text is `left-justified`, so we will also include `std::left` in the output as well. To output each line in a nice manner you can change the code above to:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
    std::cout << "substances and boiling points:\n";    /* output heading */
    while (f >> name && f >> boiling) {           /* read name/boiling pt */
        std::cout << "  " << std::setw(12) << std::left
                << name << "\t" << boiling << '\n';   /* output */
        sum += boiling;             /* add boiling to sum */
        if (boiling > max) {        /* is boiling > max, if so */
            max = boiling;          /* update max with boiling */
            namemax = name;         /* update namemax with name */
        }
        cnt++;      /* increment counter */
    }

    std::cout << "\naverage boiling pt. of " << cnt << " substances\n  "
            << sum / cnt
            << "\n\nsubstance with max boiling point\n  " << namemax
            << "  (" << max << ")\n";
```

(**note:** I included the final output line as well because I added a `'\n'` to the beginning so it would be separated from your list by a blank-line)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/boilingpt dat/boiling.txt
substances and boiling points:
  Acetaldehyde  20.8
  Acetone       50.5
  Acetylene     -84
  Ammonia       -35.5
  Aniline       184.4
  Benzene       80.4
  Chloroform    62.2
  Ethane        -88
  Ether         35
  Furfurol      161.7
  Glycerin      290
  Glycerine     290
  Naphthalene   218
  Nitrobenzene  210.9
  Petrol        95
  Petroleum     210
  Phenol        182
  Propane       -43
  Propylene     -47.7
  Tar           300
  Toluene       110.6
  Turpentine    160
  Water         100
  Xylene        142.7

average boiling pt. of 24 substances
  108.583

substance with max boiling point
  Tar  (300)
```

If you had not used `std::left` after using `std::setw(12)`, the substance names would be right-justified (again, not a bad look), e.g.

```
$ ./bin/boilingpt dat/boiling.txt
substances and boiling points:
  Acetaldehyde  20.8
       Acetone  50.5
     Acetylene  -84
       Ammonia  -35.5
       Aniline  184.4
       Benzene  80.4
    Chloroform  62.2
        Ethane  -88
         Ether  35
      Furfurol  161.7
      Glycerin  290
     Glycerine  290
   Naphthalene  218
  Nitrobenzene  210.9
        Petrol  95
     Petroleum  210
        Phenol  182
       Propane  -43
     Propylene  -47.7
           Tar  300
       Toluene  110.6
    Turpentine  160
         Water  100
        Xylene  142.7

average boiling pt. of 24 substances
  108.583

substance with max boiling point
  Tar  (300)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I am obviously quite novice and trying to understand everything, I believe the portion before the main function is a bit beyond my abilities: int main (int argc, char **argv)     as well as the first 'if' statement (is it just saying if the input file has less than 2 variables that it will not execute, essentially?).  Additionally, I forgot to mention the the output must include the list from the input file.

Comment: I edited my original post to include where I am, thus far.  Really appreciate not just the code but your explanations!

Comment: Sorry, There are two legal invocations for `main()`, (1) taking no argument `int main()` and (2) taking a list of arguments from the command line. `int main (int argc, char **argv)` where `argc` is your *argument count* (the number of parameters on the command line, `argv[0]` always holds the program name) and `argv` your *argument vector* which holds the arguments (in your case the filename to open is `argv[1]`)) The `if` statement says if the argument count is less than `2` (meaning only the program name is on the command line, with no filename) give the error and usage.

Comment: @IanRay your `inData.open("input.txt");` to open `"input.txt"` for reading, is what I do with `std::ifstream f(argv[1]);` (which declares the stream variable `f` with the `(argv[1])` -- filename to open all at once. You can change in my code `ifstream f("input.txt");` to accomplish the same thing -- but ***you never hard-code filenames or use magic-numbers*** -- that's why functions like `main()` take parameters `:)`

Comment: You mentioned a `for` loop -- which you can use in an awkward fashion to read all information from your file, but a `while` loop is generally bettered tailored for file - input -- you continue looping `while` there is still data to read. If you must use a `for` loop it is a simple change -- you can combine the `for` loop and `cnt` into the `for` loop itself (so your loop handles your counter too). Six-to-one, 1/2 dozen to another...

Comment: Your assisstance and time has been greatly appreciated.  I edited my original post to describe one last problem I am encountering, if you get the time!